# MVC Authorization for partial views and elements

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

MSDN says:

> To restrict access to an ASP.NET MVC view, you restrict access to the action method that renders the view. 
>   To accomplish this, the MVC framework provides the AuthorizeAttribute class.

I am working with an application that is loading nested Partial Views (for lack of a better term)

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
....stuff.....

return PartialView("PartialViewName", model);

}
```

In the above loaded Partial View is the nesting like:

```
PartialView.cshtml

@Html.Partial("AnotherPartial", Model)
  -@Html.Partial("AnotherPartial_Partial", Model)
    -@Html.Partial("AnotherPartial_Partial_Partial", Model)
@Html.Partial("YetAnotherPartial", Model)
@Html.Partial("StillAnotherPartial", Model)
```

What do I do when I want to allow access to one Partial View but not another? What about specific elements in those partials? Like buttons, panels, divs, textboxes, etc...

I have users and roles defined in my database, so I know who can access what element/partial view.

Currently I am using my own Html Helper to show or hide partial views:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ShowHidePartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string   partialName, TheUser user)
    {
        bool? isVisible = false;

        //If I don't know who you are or what you are trying to view
        if (user == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(partialName))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        if (IsAdmin(user))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(helper.Partial(partialName).ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            isVisible = IsVisible(partialName, user);
        }

        if (isVisible == true)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(helper.Partial(partialName).ToString());
        }

        return  MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }
```

I'll probably stick with this method for rendering partials, but I am still unsure on how to proceed with restricting access/visibility to elements within these partials.

For example, if the user has access to AnotherPartial.cshtml and there are 4 sections on that partial that allow the user to see/edit information (like member address, member status, member phone, and member date of birth) all with update/save buttons. These sections are exclusive to AnotherPartial.cshtml.

Say I only want to allow the user to view (ReadOnly) 2 sections, edit (ReadWrite) 1 section, and completely hide the 4th section (Hidden?...No Access). How would I achieve that?

I'm using Windows authentication for access to the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have actions that go with those partials, but it looks like you want to use Html.Partial so that you don't have to rebuild your model over and over again.  One thing I would do in your case is pass in the roles you want to show those partial's.  You have to be careful in this case because this doesn't fully comply with the concept of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), because you're providing some business logic within the view.  But it seems that you've already gone down this route.  So to extend your method a little bit you can do the following.  **I'm assuming that your TheUser class has a Roles property.**

```
public static MvcHtmlString ShowHidePartial(this HtmlHelper helper, string   partialName, TheUser user, string [] roles)
{
            if(roles = null)
            {
                  return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            }

    //If I don't know who you are or what you are trying to view        
    if(user != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(partialName) && user.Roles.Any(r=> roles.Contains(r)) )
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(helper.Partial(partialName).ToString());
    }

    return  MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

So now your view would look something like this:

```
@Html.ShowHidePartial("AnotherPartial", Model, new string[] {"AuthorizedRole1", "AuthorizedRole2"})
  -@Html.ShowHidePartial("AnotherPartial_Partial", Model, new string[] {"AuthorizedRole1"})
    -@Html.ShowHidePartial("AnotherPartial_Partial_Partial", Model, new string[] {"AuthorizedRole1", "AuthorizedRole3"})
@Html.ShowHidePartial("YetAnotherPartial", Model, new string[] {})
@Html.ShowHidePartial("StillAnotherPartial", Model, new string[] {})
```

**Option 2**
Build views based on the roles for example an AdminView.cshtml that contains the partials that the admin view needs.  Then in your business logic code decide on which view to execute.  This would happen outside of the view code completely and etter conform to the concept of Separation of Concerns.